# Altering the browser's interaction with css and the dom

Tags: css, dom, layout, browser, rendering

I am interested in creating a custom browser with a hacked render engine that reinterprets or automatically assigns certain css vaules no matter what the web site.

A simple example would be...
no matter what website you visit the anything with the img tag is rotated 90 degrees.

I am struggling to find any sort of starting point for this small project...any ideas or suggestions on the css/dom issue?

I plan to build out the GUI in visual basic if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Visual Basic, why not use the WebBrowser control and modify the DOM elements within that control? You can manipulate elements from within your code behind.

Comment: I took a more indepth look at Visual Basic and realized that this method could possibly work.  Hopefully this will give me the ability to affect any css of the pages visited.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to develop a browser plugin / extension.

[Chrome extensions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) are a good place to start.

If you'd like to actually like to monkey with the render engine behind a browser, check out WebKit (what Safari uses) or Gecko (what Firefox uses).